# saltstack install a new version of package from salt://files/

Tags: salt-stack, debian-packaging

working with salt 3003.1, what's the best way to install a new version package from salt://files/ assuming the same name and version?

I have this config below, but if I put a new package there without changing versions, it won't pick it up.

```
mypackage:
  pkg.installed:
    - reinstall: False
    - source: salt://files/{{ pillar['env'] }}/deb/{{ pillar['mypackagelatest'] }}
  service.running:
    - enable: True
    - require:
      - file: /etc/mypackage/mypackage.toml
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/mypackage/mypackage.toml
```

alternatively, can I use a simple https link, no repo? thanks

Answer (score 1):

`pkg.installed` is a **state module**, and hence only takes action when necessary, i.e.  it is idempotent in its action. So, unless it detects changes such as below, it will report that the specified package is already installed.

- package not installed
- package is newer than the one installed, etc.

It would be a good practice to stick to this approach and have versioned packages, so the package is updated (by Saltstack) when the version changes.

That said...

If this is not possible for some reason, then we can use the salt **execution module** `pkg.install`. Execution modules *run every time* they are called. Example:

```yaml
install-mypackage:
  module.run:
    - name: pkg.install
    - sources:
        - mypackage: salt://files/mypackage-1.0-1.deb
```

This can be undesirable at times as this will install (on every run) the package regardless of whether the version or contents have changed.

Comment: thanks, totally make sense, testing this in a bit!